# how to get a div to fill 100% of browser height except for 60px at the top and bottom?

Tags: css, html

I need a div with width of 40px to have a height of 100% minus a 60px gap at the top and another 60px gap at the bottom of the browser window? How can I do this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why you want to do that?? would you plz provide some info about you case!?

Answer (score 3):

Best way I've found is to use a `position:absolute` element with a top and bottom attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/T4SXB/

```
#blah{
    background:#fb5;
    top:60px;
    bottom:60px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
}

/* per Pumbaa's suggestion, you should ensure that the page
   doesn't have any weird formatting issues.  Also make sure
   that the #blah element doesn't have a parent with a "position"
   attribute other than "static" (the default) */
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you should add `html,body{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}`

Answer (score 1):

Simple [example](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html) demonstrating 100% height with fixed height header and footer :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the container is relative/absolute positioned, try css:

```
#outer { position: relative } // OR position: absolute
#innerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 40px;
  ...
}
```

Top and bottom can be used simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `margin` property :

```
#myDiv{
    width : 40px;
    height : 100%;
    margin-top : 60px;
    margin-bottom : 60px;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUn2V/).